When I try to build my Next JS project using npm run build, it says ECONNREFUSED. But npm run dev works perfectly


It says ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000 and same error occurs when I try to deploy the code to vercel. Never got this type of error, so not understanding why is it happening?
I tried many times but doesn't work. But npm run dev works.
Next JS Version: 14.1.3
Error is given in the terminal screenshots.
My app/api/properties/route.js code:
import { getSessionUser } from "@/utils/getSessionUser";
import cloudinary from "@/config/cloudinary";
import { createProperty, getProperties } from "@/actions/dbActions";

// export const dynamic = "force-dynamic";

///Get /api/properties
export const GET = async (request) => {
  try {
    const page = request.nextUrl.searchParams.get("page") || 1;
    const pageSize = request.nextUrl.searchParams.get("pageSize") || 6;
    const { properties, total } = await getProperties(page, pageSize);
    const result = {
      total,
      properties,
    };

    return new Response(JSON.stringify(result), {
      status: 200,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching properties:", error);
    return new Response("Something went wrong", { status: 500 });
  }
};

//Post /api/properties
export const POST = async (request) => {
  try {
    const sessionUser = await getSessionUser();

    if (!sessionUser || !sessionUser.userId) {
      return new Response(JSON.stringify({ message: "User ID is required" }), {
        status: 401,
      });
    }

    const { userId } = sessionUser;

    const formData = await request.formData();

    // Access all values from amenities and images
    const amenities = formData.getAll("amenities");
    const images = formData
      .getAll("images")
      .filter((image) => image.name !== "");

    // Create propertyData object for database
    const propertyData = {
      type: formData.get("type"),
      name: formData.get("name"),
      description: formData.get("description"),
      location: {
        street: formData.get("location.street"),
        city: formData.get("location.city"),
        state: formData.get("location.state"),
        zipcode: formData.get("location.zipcode"),
      },
      beds: formData.get("beds"),
      baths: formData.get("baths"),
      square_feet: formData.get("square_feet"),
      amenities,
      rates: {
        weekly: formData.get("rates.weekly"),
        monthly: formData.get("rates.monthly"),
        nightly: formData.get("rates.nightly."),
      },
      seller_info: {
        name: formData.get("seller_info.name"),
        email: formData.get("seller_info.email"),
        phone: formData.get("seller_info.phone"),
      },
      owner: userId,
    };

    // Upload image(s) to Cloudinary
    const imageUploadPromises = [];

    for (const image of images) {
      const imageBuffer = await image.arrayBuffer();
      const imageArray = Array.from(new Uint8Array(imageBuffer));
      const imageData = Buffer.from(imageArray);

      // Convert the image data to base64
      const imageBase64 = imageData.toString("base64");

      // Make request to upload to Cloudinary
      const result = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(
        `data:image/png;base64,${imageBase64}`,
        {
          folder: "propertypulse",
        }
      );

      imageUploadPromises.push(result.secure_url);

      // Wait for all images to upload
      const uploadedImages = await Promise.all(imageUploadPromises);
      // Add uploaded images to the propertyData object
      propertyData.images = uploadedImages;
    }

    const newProperty = await createProperty(propertyData);

    return Response.redirect(
      `${process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL}/properties/${newProperty._id}`
    );
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error adding property:", error);
    return new Response(JSON.stringify({ message: "Failed to add property" }), {
      status: 500,
    });
  }
};

